# I got fault when I fetched my data from NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I run my app and then fetched my data. Data is ok. When I run second time I got fault for my old values. What is wrong?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
    for (int i =0; i<2; i++) 
    {
        Test *test = [[[Test alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]] autorelease];
        test.text = @"Text";
        test.index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    }
    [self saveContext];
}


-(void) showValues
{    
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setEntity:entity];    
 NSError *error;    
 NSArray *array = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 NSLog(@"Array: %@ ", array);    
}
```

first run

```
2012-01-22 21:48:52.092 Mew[411:707] Array: (
"<Test: 0x183f60> (entity: Test; id: 0x1856b0 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p1> ; data: {\n    index = 0;\n    text = Text;\n})",
"<Test: 0x184940> (entity: Test; id: 0x1857e0 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p2> ; data: {\n    index = 1;\n    text = Text;\n})"
)
```

second run // first and second values are fault

```
2012-01-22 21:50:29.892 Mew[429:707] Array: (
"<Test: 0x16c950> (entity: Test; id: 0x16c720 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Test: 0x16d130> (entity: Test; id: 0x16c730 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Test: 0x1684c0> (entity: Test; id: 0x16bfd0 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p3> ; data: {\n    index = 0;\n    text = Text;\n})",
"<Test: 0x16ab90> (entity: Test; id: 0x16c100 <x-coredata://90165BCF-D2DE-4661-9B12-33EF86F0C09F/Test/p4> ; data: {\n    index = 1;\n    text = Text;\n})"
)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<fault>` does not mean that your data is corrupted. It means that it is dynamically linked with the fetched results and the actual object will be loaded when any attempt is made to access any value/property from the object. remember - you have used @dynamic in .m file?
That's why it shows `<fault>` when you `NSLog` with array and fault disappears when you access any property of the object `NSLog(@"Test: %@ ", test.text);`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a bug.

I've just change from

```
 NSLog(@"Array: %@ ", array);
```

to

```
for (Test *test in array)
{
    NSLog(@"Test: %@ ", test.text);
}
```

and fault was disappeared

Comment: that was no bug. Now you just "force" the program to load your data from core data. Make sure to remove that code from your production built. Faults are a great feature of core data to improve performance. Have a look at the documentation: [Core Data Programming Guide - Faulting and Uniquing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)