# Variable assigned from core data becomes null

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, segue

In my app I'm implementing core data. After performing fetch, I use fetched data as a data source for my table view.

I'm not very familiar with integrating NSFetchedResultsController as a table data source, so I do it differently.

```
dataSourceItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[myCoreData fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects]];
```

NSLogging the "dataSourceItems" returns fetched results (so until now it's working ok). I use it as a tableView data source, and my cells are filled with it's data.

After tapping on cell, I'm pushing another (item detail) view controller. I need to pass item id so I can do another fetch from core data.

```
     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         MainItemListCell *cell = [_tblViewitems cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.itemId);

        ItemDetailsViewController *itemDetail = [[ItemDetailsViewController alloc]
                                                                     initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailsViewController"
                                                                     bundle:nil];
        itemDetail.passedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.lblItemName.text];
        itemDetail.passedValue = cell.lblAmount.text;
        itemDetail.passedEvent =[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Assigning %@",((MyCoreDataItem *)[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).cEventId);
        itemDetail.passedId = ((MyCoreDataItem *)[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).cEventId;
        itemDetail.passedStatus = cell.lblOweStatus.text;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetail animated:YES];
}
```

From my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
Printing description of cell->_itemId:
102

itemDetail.passedId = cell._itemId;
```

After NSLogging itemDetail.passedId I get null

I also tried following:

```
itemDetail.passedId = ((ItemDetail *)[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).cEventId;

NSLog(@"Assigning %@",((ItemDetail *)[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).cEventId);

Assigning (null)
```

NSLogging the dataSourceItems returns following:

```
Printing description of dataSourceItems:
<__NSArrayM 0x176815e0>(
<ItemDetail: 0x176828a0> (entity: ItemDetail; id: 0x17681870 <x-coredata://7E065CF5-7AC9-4BBB-A3F9-05DC5B155F60/ItemDetail/p1> ; data: <fault>)
)
```

At first I thought that data: fault means error. However, I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963823/i-got-fault-when-i-fetched-my-data-from-nsmanagedobjectcontext) that faults are not errors.

However, I'm really lost as why I cannot pass core data values to my detail VC.

Comment: Are you sure dataSourceItems have data?

Comment: Even though they are <fault>, my table view gets populated with data... So I think,that it does

Comment: do you retain the `NSManagedObjectContext` that the FRC performed the fetch on? Log your `<item>.managedObjectContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first of all create your core data entity and then assign its related property to related **ItemDetailsViewController**'s object property like this.

```
MyCoreDataItem *myCoreDataItem = (MyCoreDataItem *)[dataSourceItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
itemDetail.passedId = myCoreDataItem.itemId;
```

**Note:-**
You have to create a class that inherits **NSManagedObject** named as **MyCoreDataItem** that represents a core data entity. And you have to declare properties like **itemId** and what else you want.

Comment: Well, I've tried also adding property MyCoreDataItem (which is NSManagedObject subclass) to my itemDetailsVC, and then assign it like you did in your answer.. but still null

Comment: itemDetail.passedItem =[dataSourceBundles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"EVENT %@",itemDetail.passedItem.cTitle);

returns (null) (passedItem is NSManagedObject subclass)